# How to define a lazier sum function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

How could i make the left hand sum in the expression below "less strict" such that i don't evaluate the whole list `xs`. In the example, only the first 3 elements are enough to know the result of the second expression (`True`).

```
xs=[1..10]
sum xs > 3
```

ghci:

```
λ> let xs = [1..10]
λ> :sp xs
xs = _
λ> sum xs > 3
True
λ> :sp xs
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [lazy natural](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.1.0.3/docs/Data-Number-Natural.html).

```
Prelude Data.Number.Natural> let xs = [1..10] :: [Natural]
Prelude Data.Number.Natural> :sp xs
xs = _
Prelude Data.Number.Natural> sum xs > 3
True
Prelude Data.Number.Natural> :sp xs
xs = [Data.Number.Natural.S Data.Number.Natural.Z,
      Data.Number.Natural.S
        (Data.Number.Natural.S Data.Number.Natural.Z),
      Data.Number.Natural.S _,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]
```

To go even lazier, use `foldr` instead of `foldl` the way `sum` does:

```
Prelude Data.Number.Natural> let xs = [1..10] :: [Natural]
Prelude Data.Number.Natural> let lazySum = foldr (+) 0
Prelude Data.Number.Natural> lazySum xs > 3
True
Prelude Data.Number.Natural> :sp xs
xs = Data.Number.Natural.S Data.Number.Natural.Z :
     Data.Number.Natural.S
       (Data.Number.Natural.S Data.Number.Natural.Z) :
     Data.Number.Natural.S _ : _
```

Comment: I did try defining sum with `foldr`, but it evaluated the whole list of integer. I guess I should use natural even with `foldr`.